# jQuery Cached Selector does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JavaScript and jQuery I am trying to *cache* a Selector to an Objects property.

I save `$("#dnsTitle")` to `zPanelDNS.cache.dnsTitleId`

however down in my `zPanelDNS.events` function you can see where I try using the Selector and the Cached version.

For some reason the cached version does not work as I thought it would.  I write both selectors to console log and they both find the target element but for some reason the cached version does not work.

Here is the output in console of the 2, you can see they are slightly different...

`$("#dnsTitle")` **WORKS** =

```
[div#dnsTitle.account accountTitle, context: document, selector: "#dnsTitle", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

`zPanelDNS.cache.dnsTitleId` **DOES NOT WORK** =

```
[context: document, selector: "#dnsTitle", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

The JavaScript...

```
var panelDNS = {

  unsavedChanges: false,

  init: function () {
    panelDNS.events();
  },


  cache: {
    dnsTitleId: $("#dnsTitle"),
    translation: {
      absolute: 0,
      relative: 0,
      sinceDirectionChange: 0,
      percentage: 0
    }
  },

  events: function() {

    // Activate SAVE and UNDO Buttons when Record Row EDITED
    $(document).on("keydown", "#dnsRecords input" ,function() {

        // Using Selector
        // DOES WORK
        $("#dnsTitle").find(".save, .undo").removeClass("disabled");
        console.log($("#dnsTitle"));

        // Using Cached Selector panelDNS.cache.dnsTitleId
        // DOES NOT WORK
        //panelDNS.cache.dnsTitleId.find(".save, .undo").removeClass("disabled");
        console.log(panelDNS.cache.dnsTitleId);

    });

  }

}

$(function(){
    panelDNS.init();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#dnsTitle")` looks up the element with that ID **immediately** when you call it, and returns a jQuery object wrapping the element (if found) or an empty one (if not). It doesn't re-query or something when you try to use it later. Apparently, the element with that ID doesn't exist when the code creating the `panelDNS` object is created, but *does* exist *later* when a key is pressed.

There could be any number of reasons for that. For instance, if the `script` element for your code is higher up in your HTML document than the `dnsTitle` element, that would be why; the element doesn't exist until that part of the document is parsed.

For example, this will not turn the text of the `myElement` element blue:

```
<script>
$("#myElement").css("color", "blue");
</script>
<!-- ... -->
<div id="myElement">This text will not turn blue</div>
```

but this will:

```
<div id="myElement">This text WILL turn blue</div>
<!-- ... -->
<script>
$("#myElement").css("color", "blue");
</script>
```

This is one of many reasons that, unless you have a good reason not to, you should put your `script` elements at the *bottom* of your document, just before your closing `</body>` tag. That's the recommendation from the [YUI Best Practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) and the [Google Closure Library](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41) teams.

---

There were a couple of other problems with that code, not least that it had a syntax error where you were defining `events`, and you were using `PanelDNS` and `panelDNS` interchangeably, but JavaScript is case-sensitive and so they're not the same thing.

Here's that code with the changes described above and fixes for the other problems I noticed, see inline comments with `****`:

```
var panelDNS = {

  unsavedChanges: false,

  init: function () {
    // **** Removed unnecessary second `ready` call

    // **** Get the element here
    panelDNS.cache.dnsTitleId = $("#dnsTitle");

    // **** Call the `events` function to hook events
    panelDNS.events();

    // (Instead of `panelDNS` above, you could use `this`, but since you
    // only have one `panelDNS` object, it's simpler to use that)
  },


  cache: {
    // **** Removed dnsTitleId here
    translation: {
      absolute: 0,
      relative: 0,
      sinceDirectionChange: 0,
      percentage: 0
    }
  },

  events: function() { // **** Made this a function

    // Activate SAVE and UNDO Buttons when Record Row EDITED
    $(document).on("keydown", "#dnsRecords input" ,function() {

        panelDNS.cache.dnsTitleId.find(".save, .undo").removeClass("disabled");
    });

  }

}

$(function(){
    panelDNS.init();
});
```

Comment: other important possiblity to consider is cached object won't reference element if that element's html is replaced at any time after caching...even with same ID as replacement

Comment: @charlietfl: Quite right. If we have `<div id="outer"><div id="inner">...</div></div>` and we have `inner = $("#inner");`, if code later does `$("#outer").html('<div id="inner">...</div>');`, the inner element we have a reference to will no longer be in the DOM (instead, a *new* element with that ID will be there).

Comment: Thanks for clarification how that works, I wasn't aware of that limitation.  At the bottom of the code sample you can see I call `$(function(){
    panelDNS.init();
});`  I was under the impression that calling `panelDNS.init()` also "created" the `panelDNS` object but i'm assuming that's not the case now.  So would a possible solution be to call `new panelDNS` or something similar in that code as well to create the object on DOM ready?  Or am I totally off here

Comment: @jasondavis: It's not a "limitation," it's just how it works. I certainly don't want jQuery re-querying the DOM unless I specifically ask it to. :-) You could do `this.cache.dnsTitleId = $("#dnsTitle");` within `panelDNS.init` rather than when you create the `panelDNS` object, assuming of course that the `dnsTitle` element exists at that point (e.g., you're not adding it later). Or you could stop using the `ready` event entirely and just put your script at the end of the `body` (just before the `</body>`) element. Unless you have a very good reason not to, that's normally what you should do.

Comment: @jasondavis: I've added some references for that at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder when I said limitation I only meant as far as the order of things.  As far as putting it at the bottom,its an existing project I am working on and the actual JavaScript file is included into the page as part of a `plugin system` so unfortunately I cannot really determine where it's inserted in this case.  It's very good to know how this works for future consideration though.  For now I will try your other suggestion.  So calling `this.cache.dnsTitleId = $("#dnsTitle");` sets the objects property when the `init` function is ran,...(cont)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder (continued)...  do I just set the `cache` properties as null or something where the `cache` code is or is that whole section not even needed now?Sorry I'm learning. JS has a lot of little things to learn and thanks for the help.   BTW setting that in my `init` gives this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dnsTitleId' of undefined `

Comment: @jasondavis: You can just leave off the `cache` properties you'll initialize later. JavaScript objects are very dynamic, there's no need to "declare" a property in advance or anything.

Comment: @jasondavis: I didn't notice that `init`'s code is within a *second* `ready` handler. You only need one (probably best to make it the one at the end of your code, calling `init`), not two. Also, there are two other errors: 1. In `init` you have `PanelDNS.events();`, but JavaScript is case sensitive, `PanelDNS` and `panelDNS` are not the same thing. 2. Your code as quoted has a syntax error where you're defining the `events` property. The syntax you're using is for an object, not a function, and so can only contain property initializers, not step-by-step code.

Comment: @jasondavis: I've updated the answer to include fixes to those issues. Good luck with things,

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry about that, I had changed some names and stuff when I posted on here, my real copy doesn't have any of those errors so I updated my code to reflect that on this post.  I do have the Double use of Document ready as I just added the second 1 tonight, I will remove the `init` version of it though

Comment: If you have time maybe you could clarify why `this.cache.dnsTitleId` does not work in this case and `panelDNS.cache.dnsTitleId` has to be used?  If not its no big deal i appreciate your answers! Thank you

Comment: @jasondavis: The value of `this` inside the `ready` callback is different than the value of `this` inside the call to `init`, but both of those functions close over the same `panelDNS` variable. More about `this`: *[Mythical Methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)*, *[You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)* More about closures: *[Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)*